# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un formulario a otro formulario en Visual Basic (una clonación de datos)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server

Este es el código que uso  ,no me pasan los requerimientos de aprobadores y centro de costo que antes ya llené en su tabs correspondientes, pero al momento de clonar los combos,no me trae el dato guardado.

```
Private Function GrabarRQClonado() As Boolean
    Dim AccordionAprobadoresCentroCosto As Integer = 1, nIdCentroCosto As Integer, nIdMotivo As Integer = 1, nIdEstado As Integer = 10
    Dim cNombreContacto As String = String.Empty, cTelefonoContacto As String = String.Empty
    Dim oPasajero As Perfil = Perfil.ObtenerPasajeroID(CboPasajero.SelectedValue)

    Integer.TryParse(oPasajero.CCentroID, nIdCentroCosto)
    If IdRequerimiento = 0 Then 'REVISAR
        nIdEstado = 10 'RQ PENDIENTE
    Else
        nIdEstado = 1 'RQ ACTIVO
    End If

    Dim oRequerimientoNew As Requerimiento = New Requerimiento(0, nIdCentroCosto, AccordionAprobadoresCentroCosto,
                    nIdMotivo, TxtFecha_reserva.Text, CboPasajero.SelectedItem.Text, _
                    CboPasajero.SelectedValue, TxtTitulo.Text, "1", True, TxtTelefono_pax.Text, _
                    TxtDireccion_pax.Text, CboTipoDocumento.SelectedValue, txtndoc_identidad.Text, _
                    cNombreContacto, cTelefonoContacto, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, _
                    String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, _
                    String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, nIdEstado, 0, Seguridad.Obtenerlogin, Now, _
                    Seguridad.Obtenerlogin, Now, TxtPasaporte.Text, "", "", "", Seguridad.ObtenerEmpresaID, 0, 0, _
                    0, 0, 0, "", Now, Me.HRefAdjunto.HRef, Me.FileUploadAdjunto.FileName, _
                    String.Empty, String.Empty)
    If Not oRequerimientoNew.Save() Then
        Return False
    End If
    IdRequerimiento = oRequerimientoNew.Id_Requerimiento
    BindData()
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Hola Laox, Bienvenido a So en Español, podrias agregarle un contexto a tu pregunta explicando lo que quieres lograr y si has intentado algo, ya que una pregunta solo con codigo puede ser confusa para los usuarios que buscan ayudarte y podrias obtener respuestas que no aplican para ti

Comment: 0k gracias por la recomendación , soy nuevo en esto , trato de ser lo mas explicativo , ojala me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Revisa el codigo que has publicado porque no esta todo contenido en el bloque de codigo, si te deja edita la pregunta. Ademas no entendi, que seria esto de clonar los combos ? No relaciono el codigo que muestras con los combos que mencionas

Comment: Visita este sitio y descarga el ejemplo que publiqué, creo que es la mejor forma de que lo veas, caso contrario contactame a ver que mas puedo hacer por ti http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9096&lngWId=10 Saludos
maximiliano.gil@gmail.com